# Clicking Select All in this HTML window

Tags: html, vba, checkbox, getelementbyid

Help Everyone,

I have VBA code to open up the report picture as shown below, it will select ERX IE WORKFUSION HOA from the first drop-down list, click View Report (as that is the only way to show the options in the User drop-down box), and then I want it to select "Select All" from the User list. Unfortunately, the User list is not created the same way in HTML as the User Group one, so I cannot mimic what I've done there.

I am getting a Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set error on the following line near the bottom **.document.getelementbyId("ct132_ct104_ct107_divDropDown_ct100").Click**

```
Sub Import_DCTR_Bot_Prod()

'Set Variables
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim targetURL As String
Dim webcontent As String
Dim sh
Dim eachIE

targetURL = "http://lousrswpl10:8081/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f12717%2fReports%2fWorkflow%2fePostRx+Detailed+Audit+Report&ViewMode=Detail"
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate targetURL

'Navigate to ePostRx Detailed Audit Report
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

Do
    Set sh = New Shell32.Shell
    For Each eachIE In sh.Windows
        If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, targetURL) Then
            Set IE = eachIE
            Exit Do
            End If
        Next eachIE
    Loop
Set eachIE = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

'Select ERX IE WORKFUSION HOA from User Group
With IE
    .Document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue").Value = "42"
    .Document.Forms(0).submit
End With

With IE
    .Document.getElementById("ct132_ct104_ct107_divDropDown_ct100").Click
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Here's what the HTML says on the actual Select All checkbox:

```
<INPUT onclick="$get('ctl32_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);" id=ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00 type=checkbox value="" name=ctl32$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl00>
```

Comment: Have you also checked that IE is not nothing?

Comment: I tried to place between code tags but it was pasting it in spurts and not into an entire code block for some reason so it looked really confusing. I will edit. Also, I'm very familiar with VBA but less with HTML, still learning. What do I need to do to check that IE is not nothing?

Comment: Code is now removed as a picture and placed inside code tags, apologize everyone.

Comment: The html can be pasted using snippet tool (it's the [edit] icon one on the far right with <>) ; you then add htm to top left box. You check ie is not nothing at after this line _Set sh = Nothing_ just to be sure you do actually have an IE object. If you execute line by line with F8 does the error go away?

Comment: @QHarr IE is not nothing after that line. Executing the lines with F8 does not make the error go away. Still receive the object variable or with block variable not set error. Is there a way to select the select all box there without using "Click", I could try that route maybe.

Comment: @QHarr anything else you can suggest?